# How can I print "\t" (as it looks) in Java?

Tags: java, string

I want to print backslash t in Java. But whenever I try, it actualy takes it as \t operator.
Double backslash didn't work. How can I do that.

Answer (score 16):

Escape the backslash by adding another, for example

```
System.out.println("This is a tab \t and this is not \\t");
```

If this doesn't work, there might be something else wrong in your code - please post it if this doesn't help you.

Answer (score 8):

You need to escape the '\' with another '\'

```
System.out.println("\\t");
```

Answer (score 3):

The double backslash works.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
System.out.println("\\t");
}
```

will output \t

Comment: @Steve Kuo: because it would be pretty lame to mistakingly write, say, *args = new String[0]* while you meant to write, say *coolArgs = new String[0]* to then not realize (because you just created a bug) you're not passing the *args* passed to your Java program.  Note that tools that do perform automated Java software verification can be configured to report every single place where *final* could be used and is not (which may ring a clue bell).

Comment: @Steve Kuo: you should also realize that Java **could** have been created with every single "variable" being *final* by default and then mandating the use of, say, *var* if you wanted to modify later on that variable.  In that case we'd have had: *public static void main(String[] args) {...}* and **anyone** changing this to *public static void main(var String[] args) {...}* would have looked like a fool, because there's really not justification for changing *args*.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: Eclipse can be set to automatically make variables final wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println("\"\t\""); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("\"\\t\"");
```

if you need even the double quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

To add tab in java the process same like c and java

**In C:-**
`printf("This will display the tab example \t After tab");`

**In Java:-**
`System.out.println("This will display the tab example \t After tab");`
**Same will be for New line also**
`System.out.println("This will display the New Line example \n Next Line");`

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants to print a literal `\t` _not_ a `tab` character.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("\" + "t");
```

this wille print: `\t` easy!

Answer (score 0):

```java
System.out.println("\\"+"\\t");
```

Shows:
`\t`