# Checking HTML (Website) tags within Java Code

Tags: java, html, regex

I have system in PHP that the user enters a website url and we download the html and check values in tags.  I have to rewrite it in java now.  I been search for days and cant find any easy way to do the following tasks.

1) download HTML based on URL

2) After downloading HTML check values in tags

THIS WILL NOT BUILD! CAN SOMEONE HELP ME

```
public String tagValue(String inHTML, String tag) throws DataNotFoundException
    {
        String value = null;

        String searchFor = "/<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\/" + tag + "\>/";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=([^ >]*)[^>]*>([^<]*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inHTML);

        return value;

    }
```

Comment: What do you want to check for inside the tags?

Answer (score 0):

1. check out http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html
2. google "java html parser" for options. you could also use [regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) if the requirements are fairly simple and straightforward.

An example follows. It took me a while, I haven't worked with these APIs for a long time.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~/tmp$ cat test.java; javac test.java; java test
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class test {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  URL target = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
  URLConnection connection = target.openConnection();
  connection.connect();
  String html = "", line = null;
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
   connection.getInputStream()));
  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) html += line;
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=([^ >]*)[^>]*>([^<]*)");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
  System.out.println("href\ttext");
  while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "\t" + matcher.group(2));
  }
 }
}
href    text
"/" 
"/domains/" Domains
"/numbers/" Numbers
"/protocols/"   Protocols
"/about/"   About IANA
"/go/rfc2606"   RFC 2606
"/about/"   About
"/about/presentations/" Presentations
"/about/performance/"   Performance
"/reports/" Reports
"/domains/" Domains
"/domains/root/"    Root Zone
"/domains/int/" .INT
"/domains/arpa/"    .ARPA
"/domains/idn-tables/"  IDN Repository
"/protocols/"   Protocols
"/numbers/" Number Resources
"/abuse/"   Abuse Information
"http://www.icann.org/" Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers
"mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback" iana@iana.org
```

Comment: We're now at Java 7, and you're still linking to JDK 1.4.2 documentation. You should at least point to Java 6 api doc.

Comment: i am trying this but will not build? public String tagValue(String inHTML, String tag) throws DataNotFoundException
 {
  String value = null;
  
  String searchFor = "/<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\/" + tag + "\>/";
  
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=([^ >]*)[^>]*>([^<]*)");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inHTML);
    
  return value;
  
 }

Comment: get rid of the unnecessary escape characters (backslashes), or if they're necessary see sleske's response.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) download HTML based on URL

There are various options. There are some helper libraries, e.g. [Apache HTTPComponents](http://hc.apache.org/). You can also just use Java's built-in classes. See e.g. [java code to download a file from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335610/java-code-to-download-a-file-from-server) .

> 2) After downloading HTML check values in tags

You probably want to use an HTML parser. For *very* simple cases, you could use regular expressions (as it seems you are trying to in your example), but this quickly leads to problems. See this famous question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

> THIS WILL NOT BUILD! CAN SOMEONE HELP ME

To put a "\" (backslash) into a literal Java string, you need to double it (because \ is used to introduce special sequences in a Java string literal). So to get a string with just a "\", write it as

```
String myBackslash = "\\";
```

See e.g. [How can I print "\t" (as it looks) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979142/how-can-i-print-t-as-it-looks-in-java)

Comment: thanks but I still cant get it to return the right value - public String tagValue(String inHTML, String tag) throws DataNotFoundException
 {
  String value = null;
  
  String searchFor = "/<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\\/" + tag + "\\>/";
  
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchFor);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inHTML);
    
  return value;
  
 }

Comment: @Johnathan Smith: Please edit your question, and indicate: 1) The modified code you used, 2) the input you used, 3) the output you got, and why it is not what you expected. Maybe then we can help.